# T-SQL - Aggregate (MIN/MAX date) considering chronological sequence - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I can not imagine how to fix my problem using t-sql.

- I need MIN(ValidFrom) and MAX(ValidTo) out of a table with different time blocks considering a chronological sequence and a number.
- A normal group won't work because MIN(ValidFrom) and MAX(ValidTo) for num 100 will not be correct.
- I can not imagine how to get the expected results from this table using any analytic or rank function in t-sql.

I need minimum and maximum dates out of the following table.

| ValidFrom | ValidTo | Num | ID Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **2019-06-01** | 2019-12-31 | **100** | **01234567** |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-31 | 100 | 01234567 |
| 2020-04-01 | 2020-12-31 | 100 | 01234567 |
| 2021-01-01 | **2021-01-31** | 100 | 01234567 |
| **2021-02-01** | 2021-03-31 | **50** | **01234567** |
| 2021-04-01 | 2021-09-30 | 50 | 01234567 |
| 2021-10-01 | **2021-12-31** | 50 | 01234567 |
| **2022-01-01** | **2022-04-30** | **100** | **01234567** |

Expected result of the query:

| ValidFrom | ValidTo | Num | ID Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-06-01 | 2021-01-31 | 100 | 01234567 |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-12-31 | 50 | 01234567 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-30 | 100 | 01234567 |

Comment: This is known as a "gaps and islands" problem. If you give this methodology a search, you'll find a wealth of resources.

Comment: add what you have achieved so far, so that users can help you form there.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for pointing out the gaps-and-islands problem. Very good to know. I will keep it in mind. Based on the assumption that there can be no gaps or overlaps, I prefer a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ranking can be calculated based on 2 `ROW_NUMBER`.
Once you have the ranking, it's simple to aggregate.

> ```
> -- rank via ascending row_number + descending row_number
> SELECT
>   MIN(ValidFrom) AS ValidFrom
> , MAX(ValidTo) AS ValidTo
> , Num
> , [ID Number]
> -- , Rnk
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT *
>     , Rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID Number] ORDER BY ValidFrom ASC, ValidTo ASC)
>           + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID Number], Num ORDER BY ValidFrom DESC, ValidTo DESC)
>     FROM your_table
> ) q
> GROUP BY [ID Number], Num, Rnk
> ORDER BY [ID Number], MIN(ValidFrom)
> ```

| ValidFrom | ValidTo | Num | ID Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-06-01 | 2021-01-31 | 100 | 1234567 |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-12-31 | 50 | 1234567 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-30 | 100 | 1234567 |

**Second method**

> ```
> -- rank via summing flag on change
> SELECT
>   MIN(ValidFrom) AS ValidFrom
> , MAX(ValidTo) AS ValidTo
> , Num
> , [ID Number]
> , Rnk
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT *
>   , Rnk = SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID Number] ORDER BY ValidFrom, ValidTo)
>   FROM
>   (
>     SELECT *
>     , flag = IIF(Num = LAG(Num) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID Number] ORDER BY ValidFrom, ValidTo), 0, 1)
>     FROM your_table
>   ) q1
> ) q2
> GROUP BY [ID Number], Num, Rnk
> ORDER BY [ID Number], MIN(ValidFrom)
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d00c2ebb5a608574b2ecd0d04ac78b59)*

Comment: Adding row_numbers will not merge consecutive dates if there are alternating validfrom dates per Num.. eg. 50(Jan 1-March 31), 100 (Feb 1-April 30), 50(April 1 - May 31)..

Comment: @lptr The sample data doesn't have overlaps, nor duplicates. Else this would be more complicated.

Comment: @LukStorms Thanks, a lot for this idea combining 2 ROW_NUMBERS. This works for 99.9% of my cases and is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @ManuK. I've included a second method. It has an extra depth of sub-query, but the correctness of the calculated rank is more certain.